# How to avoid defining unwanted cache in ehcache

Tags: java, spring, maven, caching, ehcache

I am having a common method in a module annotated with `@Cacheable`. This method is called from two different applications both are using ehcache. But application1 doesn't want the cached result and application2 need to get result from cache. So I skipped defining cache in application1/src/main/resources/ehcache.xml If I did like this, the application throws a **IllegalArgumentException Cannot find cache named "people.list"**

How to avoid caching the method only in application1? or Is it possible to enable `@Cacheable` only for specific context?

Comment: Any inputs will be really appreciated.

Comment: What about defining the cache in application1 also, but setting the TTL to 0?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to address this is to have a different Spring configuration that would use [`NoOpCacheManager`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/support/NoOpCacheManager.html) in application 1.

If that is not an option and you want Ehcache caching disabled in the whole JVM, you can use the following system property: `net.sf.ehcache.disabled`. Setting it to true will make all caches ignore write operations.